# Hibernate JPA update multi threads single entity

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, jpa, sql-update

I have message queue, that gives messages with some entity field update info. There are 10 threads, that process messages from the queue.

For example

- 1st thread processes message, this thread should update field A from my entity with id 123.
- 2nd thread processes another message, this thread should  update field B from my entity with id 123 at the same time.

Sometimes after updates database don't contain some updated fields.

some updater:

```
someService.updateEntityFieldA(entityId, newFieldValue);
```

some service:

```
public Optional<Entity> findById(String entityId) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(new DBWorker().findOne(Entity.class, entityId));
}

public void updateEntityFieldA(String entityId, String newFieldValue) {
    findById(entityId).ifPresent(entity -> {
        entity.setFieldA(newFieldValue);
        new DBWorker().update(entity);
    });
}
```

db worker:

```
public <T> T findOne(final Class<T> type, Serializable entityId) {
    T findObj;

    try (Session session = HibernateUtil.openSessionPostgres()) {
        findObj = session.get(type, entityId);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new HibernateException("database error. " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }

    return findObj;
}

public void update(Object entity) {
    try (Session session = HibernateUtil.openSessionPostgres()) {
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.update(entity);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new HibernateException("database error. " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

HibernateUtil.openSessionPostgres() gets each time new session from

```
sessionFactory.openSession()
```

Is it possible do such logic without threads locks / optimistic locking and pessimistic locking?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `sessionFactory.openSession()` to always open a new session, on the update hibernate may be lossing the info about the dirty fields it needs to update, so issues and update to all fields.

Setting `hibernate.show_sql` property to `true` will show you the SQL `UPDATE` statements generated by hibernate.

Try refactoring your code to, in the same transaction, load the entity and update the field. A `session.update` is not needed, as the entity is managed, on transaction commit hibernate will flush changes and issue a SQL update.